# What is faster from an performance standpoint of view?

Tags: c++, performance, gcc, compiler-optimization

Which sequential implementation would be faster from a performance standpoint of view (I do realize that the 2nd one takes more memory and time to write the value in RAM):

```
for(int j=3; j<=ceil(sqrt(i));j++){
...
}
```

vs

```
int max=ceil(sqrt(i));
for(int j=3; j<=max;j++){
...
}
```

It has something to do with how compiler treats this code. Any hints on where to look for the answer are welcome.

**P.S.:** Plz do not suggest a bold and straightforward way of checking the performance by just running it. I must remind that the architectures of the underlying systems may vary drastically. So first case may win on one architecture while the second case might dominate on the other. Which is why I need a clearly defined treatment of both. Which would probably be compiler specification, let's restrict the case to gcc. From which point the question would be: which section of compiler specs I'd look in to find it?

Comment: "Any hints on where to look for the answer are welcome." - run them both on your computer and time them?

Comment: From a language purity point of view, using either "a standpoint" or "a point of view" would be preferable.

Comment: Run both variants a million times, and time it. Or look and compare the generated code for both alternatives. Odds are that the compiler will optimize the first variant to the second anyway.

Comment: I would prefer the second one for clarity. Speed is irrelevant as I can't see how a few nanoseconds will have a larger bearing on the overall operational time of the application. Have you profiled the application to make sure this is the bottleneck in performance?

Comment: That depends on many things, such as which compiler and hardware you're using. For most modern machines and most cases, your assumption about RAM in the second case is wrong. A good compiler will generate the same code for both. Look at the assembly.

Comment: U all suggest such a bold and straightforward way of checking the performance. I must remind that the architectures of the underlying systems may vary drastically. So first case may win on one architecture while the second case might dominate on the other. Which is why I need a clearly defined treatment of both. Which would probably be compiler specification, let's restrict the case to gcc, at which point I have no idea where exactly to look for it.

Comment: @DenysS.: An architecture so drastically different that it can evaluate ceil(sqrt(x)) using less stack slots or registers than needed for storing the result? Please...

Comment: I'm doing HPC... theoretically yes, it can.

Comment: @DenysS. No, you're creating an issue where there is none. You can go about examining the generated assembly code and measuring both architectures, then take educated decisions for each and/or both. You don't approach performance problems on an abstract level if you're worried the performance assumptions change below that abstraction.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis, that is provided that I have an access to the architecture atm. However my task is to do certain analysis. You on the other had try to go off topic and argue that I should be bolder and never think about such things. So who is creating an issue?

Comment: The fact that "architectures...may vary drastically" makes it *more* important to actually look at the data rather than speculate about it, not *less* important.

Comment: @DenysS. I'm not suggesting to not think about your problem. I'm suggesting thinking about **concrete data** on your problem.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis, how is "how do I know which code is faster given that I have varying architectures?" not concrete?

Comment: One cannot know which is faster by virtue of simply looking at C code. We can take this further in chat if you wish.

Comment: Well that's why I'm asking where to look at the compiler code. Can you give an argument why your statement is true?

Comment: If you want to go over gcc code, see "Loop optimization" here - http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/RTL-passes.html

Comment: no problem. You can also test it with `-fno-loop-optimize`

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends. If the compiler is able to proof that i is not changed during execution of the loop constant propagation may remove the repeated evaluation of sqrt() and ceil(). If the compiler cannot be sure that i is constant during execution it has no choice but to evaluate ceil(sqrt()) again and again in the first example.

Comment: Wouldn't any possible side effects of those functions need to be ruled out, before the compiler can move the calls out of the loop?

Comment: @Bgie: Most optimizing compilers worth their salt have builtin knowledge of potentially performance critical standard C library functions. But yes, you are right that the compiler must prove that there are no relevant side effects.

Answer (score 0):

I did some measurements and used the code at the bottom (feel free to use also).

- Results in VC2013 (intel core i3 1.80GHz):

> ```
>   TIME FUN1 = 73.8 milli-seconds
>   TIME FUN2 = 72.2 milli-seconds
> ```

- Results in GCC v4.7.2 (don't have characteristics):

> ```
>   TIME FUN1 = 23.7 milli-seconds
>   TIME FUN2 = 23.5 milli-seconds
> ```

It seems that the second method slightly outperforms the first one (I think it is what was expected). However, is not slower by orders of magnitude. In my humble opinion, the difference is very small to end up in a safe conclusion. Clearly, compiler optimizations and system architecture play a major role.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <chrono>

// facility to measure time
template<typename TimeT = std::chrono::milliseconds>
struct ExecTime
{
    template<typename F>
    static typename TimeT::rep exec(F const &func)
    {
        auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        func();
        auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast< TimeT>(
            std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start);
        return duration.count();
    }
};

// dummy function to call in loop
void dummy() { int a = 0; }

int main()
{
  int const iters = 30;
  double d = 999999999999.0;
  auto fun1 = [&]() {for (int j = 3; j <= ceil(sqrt(d)); j++) dummy();};
  auto fun2 = [&]() {int max = ceil(sqrt(d)); for (int j = 3; j <= max; j++) dummy(); };

  double time1 = 0.0;
  for(int i = 0; i < iters; ++i) {
    time1 += ExecTime<>::exec(fun1);
  }
  double time2 = 0.0;
  for (int i = 0; i < iters; ++i) {
    time2 += ExecTime<>::exec(fun1);
  }
  std::cout << "TIME FUN1 = " << time1 / static_cast<double>(iters) << " milli-seconds" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "TIME FUN2 = " << time2 / static_cast<double>(iters) << " milli-seconds" << std::endl;

  return(0);
}
```